# What time NPCs arrive at your town in Terraria once their requirements are met?

Tags: terraria

The timing I believe is around morning when the Terraria NPCs arrival which requirements are met (I'm not sure about respawning). But has anyone been keeping track on the exact time they arrive?

Answer (score 5):

If its daytime it will usually will have 1 NPC every 2 Minutes.

If its night time the NPCs will not spawn.

However it also affects if a bloodmoon has happened. If a Bloodmoon has occured the NPC will not spawn for the first 10 minutes of the day after.

Officially Day starts 4:30 game time

[Read more here](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/NPC)

Answer (score -2):

About 5 NPCs spawn a day on the mobile version of Terraria and after a bloodmoon they will not spawn in pre-Hardmode.

Comment: NPC's do spawn after a blood moon. Can I ask where you got that info from?